# Rerender FullCalendar on Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I don't know how to re-render (or re-draw) a full-calendar in Angular (@fullcalendar/resource-timeline). After I call the API, the data used to draw calendar is changed, and I hope the calendar will be updated (re-rendered). But I don't know how to do that. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's hard to help you without any code shown.

Comment: Are you talking about updating the calendar to download new events from the server? In that case, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents would help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  @ViewChild('calendar', { static: true }) calendar: FullCalendarComponent
  
  this.calendar.getApi().render()
```